# Count of values per row that do not satisfy a condition

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I want to compare the values in column `1/01`, 
`1/02`,`1/03`, `1/04`, `1/05`, `1/06` with the values in target column using the condition in the `criteria` column. I want to get the count of all values that didn't meet the criteria for each ID in the column `Sum`.

```
# importing pandas as pd 
import pandas as pd 

# Create sample dataframe
 raw_data = {'ID': ['A1', 'B1', 'C1', 'D1'], 
'Domain': ['Finance', 'IT', 'IT', 'Finance'], 
'Target': [1, 2, 3, 1], 
'Criteria':['<=', '<=', '>=', '>='],
"1/01":[0.9, 1.1, 2.1, 1],
"1/02":[0.4, 0.3, 0.5, 0.9], 
"1/03":[1, 1, 4, 1.1], 
"1/04":[0.7, 0.7, 0.1, 1],
"1/05":[0.7, 0.7, 0.1, 1], 
"1/06":[0.9, 1.1, 2.1, 1],}



 df = pd.DataFrame(raw_data, columns = ['ID', 'Domain', 'Target','Criteria', '1/01', 
'1/02','1/03', '1/04','1/05', '1/06','Sum'])
```

Expected output example:

```
   ID   Domain  Target Criteria  1/01  1/02  1/03  1/04  1/05  1/06  Sum
0  A1  Finance       1       <=   0.9   0.4   1.0   0.7   0.7   0.9  0.0
1  B1       IT       2       <=   1.1   0.3   1.0   0.7   0.7   1.1  0.0
2  C1       IT       3       >=   2.1   0.5   4.0   0.1   0.1   2.1  5.0
3  D1  Finance       1       >=   1.0   0.9   1.1   1.0   1.0   1.0  1.0
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just selectively count the rows where your criteria is violated using `np.where`. This is optimised for problems with <= and >= as the only possible criterion.

```
# `.to_numpy()` will work for pandas versions >= 0.24. 
# For older versions, use .values.
dates = df.iloc[:,4:].to_numpy()
target = df[['Target']].to_numpy()

df['Sum'] = np.where(
  (df['Criteria'] == '<=')[:,None], dates > target, dates < target).sum(axis=1)
df

   ID   Domain  Target Criteria  1/01  1/02  1/03  1/04  1/05  1/06  Sum
0  A1  Finance       1       <=   0.9   0.4   1.0   0.7   0.7   0.9    0
1  B1       IT       2       <=   1.1   0.3   1.0   0.7   0.7   1.1    0
2  C1       IT       3       >=   2.1   0.5   4.0   0.1   0.1   2.1    5
3  D1  Finance       1       >=   1.0   0.9   1.1   1.0   1.0   1.0    1
```

Comment: Its working now, i just made a change. instead of dates = df.filter(regex=r'\d/\d{2}').to_numpy() i did dates = df.iloc[:,4:].values

Comment: @krijan Great, and that would mean the Sum column should also be dropped before-hand (or not be present at all, right?).

Comment: Correct, it was just a mistake for dates, i guess they didnt put dates in correct format in excel file, thats why the function couldnt recognize the dates columns. So we had to do iloc way and extract all the dates columns. :)

Answer (score 1):

Idea is use [operators](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27278969) for compare by filtered rows, get non matched values by [`DataFrame.mask`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.mask.html) and last `sum` with assign to new column - this operations are in loop by all operators in dictionary:

```
import operator


ops = { '>=': operator.lt,
       '<=': operator.gt}

for k, v in ops.items():
    mask = df['Criteria'].eq(k).values
    df1 = df.iloc[mask, 4:]
    df.loc[mask, 'new'] = (v)(df1,df.loc[mask, 'Target'].values[:, None]).sum(axis=1)
print (df)
   ID   Domain  Target Criteria  1/01  1/02  1/03  1/04  1/05  1/06  Sum  new
0  A1  Finance       1       <=   0.9   0.4   1.0   0.7   0.7   0.9  0.0  0.0
1  B1       IT       2       <=   1.1   0.3   1.0   0.7   0.7   1.1  0.0  0.0
2  C1       IT       3       >=   2.1   0.5   4.0   0.1   0.1   2.1  5.0  5.0
3  D1  Finance       1       >=   1.0   0.9   1.1   1.0   1.0   1.0  1.0  1.0
```

Comment: Hello, Thank you for your answer. I really appreciate it. However, the "New" column should output, how many values have not meet the criteria. Example: for ID C1, we have target of 3 and criteria is saying '>=' for 3. For dates column we have only 1 value that is '>=' to 3, which, the value is 4. Then the output should be 1. since its only 1 value that is '>=' to 3. Hence, basically i want to know how i can do that :) pleases.

Comment: I fixed my question, you can see the expected output of what i need, i hope that helps :).

Comment: @krijan - so criteria are only `<=` and `<=` ?

Comment: @krijan - yes, so there are only `<=` and `>=` values in `criteria` column?