# How to use Argument as a Function name ? Python

Tags: python, pandas

Hello i want to get argument and use as a function.
Here is an example code :

```
def DropSpecificRows (self, columnName ):
    '''Drop specific rows'''
    self.data = self.data.drop(self.data[self.data.columnName < 18])
```

Error :

```
AttributeError: 'DataFrame' object has no attribute 'columnName'
```

columnName will be the column name in dataframe. How can i make this possible?
Or an operator. I want to get all this elements from user.

Comment: Use `self.data = self.data.drop(self.data[self.data[columnName] < 18])`

Comment: Better `self.data = self.data[self.data[columnName] >=18]` - changed `<` to `>=` with [`boolean indexing`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/indexing.html#boolean-indexing)

Comment: Allright, soo can i make this possible for an operator too? (<= or > etc)

Comment: Not easy, but possible, check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27278872/using-an-operator-to-add-in-python/27278969#27278969)